# Cannot call getter method unless specifying "this" keyword

Tags: c++

Why does the example from a tutorial page works without having the this keyword in the constructor?

The code from the website:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Rectangle {

 int width, height;

   public:
   Rectangle ();
   Rectangle (int,int);    
   int getWidth() {
      return width;
   }
};

Rectangle::Rectangle () {
  width = 5;
  height = 5;
}

Rectangle::Rectangle (int a, int b) {
  width = a;
  height = b;
}

int main () {
  Rectangle rect (3,4);
  Rectangle rectb;
  cout << "rect area: " << rect.getWidth() << endl;
  cout << "rectb area: " << rectb.getWidth() << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

My code:

```
class Person {
  int age;
  std::string name;

public:
  Person();
  Person(int, std::string);

  std::string * getName() {
    return &name;
  }

  int * getAge() {
    return &age;
  }
};

Person::Person () {
  age = 25;
  name = "John";
}

Person::Person (int age, std::string name){

// This is the part :
  this->age = age;
  this->name = name;

}

int main() {
  Person john(45, "Doe");
  printf("Name %d \n", *john.getAge() );
  std::cout << "Age " << *john.getName() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

As you can see in my code i must use `this->name`, if I don't then the values are not assigned.

On the other hand, the example code from the website works with or without `this->`

Why does this happen?

Comment: How else will the compiler distinguish between the `age` and `name` you have defined in your parameter list with the `age` and `name` that are class members?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the parameters of the function have the same name as the class so the compiler doesn't know which one you are talking about unless you use `this`.  You can solve this by changing the names of the variables or you could use a member initialization list

```
Person::Person (int age, std::string name) : name(name), age(age) {}
```

As a note I like to use the same name as the class variable but add a `_` after the name to make it different. So in this case I would have done:

```
Person::Person (int age_, std::string name_) : name(name_), age(age_) {}
```

This makes it easier to differentiate between the class members and the constructor parameters.

Comment: Oh, so that was it! In the future i will use different parameter/variable names.

Comment: @Ferrante Half right, please use a member initialization list.

Comment: @Ferrante That is normally a good idea.  I like to use the same name as the class variable but add a _ after the name to make it different.  So int this case I would have done `Person::Person (int age_, std::string name_) : name(name_), age(age_) {}`

Comment: @Ferrante No problem.  Glad to help.

Comment: _"That way with just a look you know which variable is which."_ Hmm, I think I'd keep forgetting whether the trailing underscore means "data member" or "function parameter".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sarcasm or do you have a better suggestion?

Comment: @NathanOliver: I don't see how you read sarcasm in what I said. I was merely commenting on your statement, suggesting that I'm not sure but I might disagree with it. Sorry to have bothered you then.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Don't be sorry.  I just wasn't sure if you were actually disagreeing with what I said or just making a joke.  I have changed the wording a little bit.  Let me know if that is more agreeable.

Answer (score 1):

```
Person::Person (int age, std::string name){

// This is the part :
   this->age = age;
   this->name = name;

}
```

Because your private variable is called name, and the variable you send in is also called name, you use this-> to specify which variable called name you are using.